# Makefile issue when trying to compile an application that uses net-snmp and rapidjson

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I am compiling a snmp agent application using net-snmp and compiling it correctly with this Makefile:

```
CC = gcc

SRC = $(shell find . -name '*.c')
OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)
TARGET = agent_daemon

CFLAGS = -I. `net-snmp-config --cflags`
# CFLAGS = -I. `net-snmp-config --cflags` `rapidjson`
BUILDLIBS = `net-snmp-config --libs`
BUILDAGENTLIBS = `net-snmp-config --agent-libs`

# shared library flags (assumes gcc)
DLFLAGS = -fPIC -shared

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(BUILDAGENTLIBS)

clean:
    rm -Rf $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Now I need to use the rapidjson library in one of the snmp agent's .c files.

rapidson is installed in /usr/include/rapidjson

In the .c file I have added the following include:

```
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
```

And the source code that is using rapidjson is this:

```
  char readBuffer[65536];

  FILE* fp = fopen("my_config_file.json", "r");
  FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));

  Document doc;
  doc.ParseStream(is);
  char jsonKey[21];

  fclose(fp);

  StringBuffer buffer;
  Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
  doc.Accept(writer);
  printf("JSON: %s\n", buffer.GetString());
```

In order to be able to compile the version of the SNMP agent that uses rapidjson I have changed in the previous Makefile the line:

```
CC = gcc
```

For :

```
CC = g++
```

However, when compiling it with the new Makefile, I get these errors:

```
readConfigFile.c:42:3: error: ‘FileReadStream’ was not declared in this scope
   FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
   ^
readConfigFile.c:42:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from readConfigFile.c:17:0:
/usr/include/rapidjson/filereadstream.h:33:7: note:   ‘rapidjson::FileReadStream’
 class FileReadStream {
       ^
readConfigFile.c:44:3: error: ‘Document’ was not declared in this scope
   Document doc;
   ^
readConfigFile.c:44:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from readConfigFile.c:18:0:
/usr/include/rapidjson/document.h:1889:34: note:   ‘rapidjson::Document’
 typedef GenericDocument<UTF8<> > Document;
                                  ^
readConfigFile.c:45:3: error: ‘doc’ was not declared in this scope
   doc.ParseStream(is);
   ^
readConfigFile.c:45:19: error: ‘is’ was not declared in this scope
   doc.ParseStream(is);
                   ^
readConfigFile.c:50:3: error: ‘StringBuffer’ was not declared in this scope
   StringBuffer buffer;
   ^
readConfigFile.c:50:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/rapidjson/writer.h:29:0,
                 from readConfigFile.c:19:
/usr/include/rapidjson/stringbuffer.h:69:38: note:   ‘rapidjson::StringBuffer’
 typedef GenericStringBuffer<UTF8<> > StringBuffer;
                                      ^
readConfigFile.c:51:3: error: ‘Writer’ was not declared in this scope
   Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
   ^
readConfigFile.c:51:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from readConfigFile.c:19:0:
/usr/include/rapidjson/writer.h:56:7: note:   ‘rapidjson::Writer’
 class Writer {
       ^
readConfigFile.c:51:31: error: ‘buffer’ was not declared in this scope
   Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
                               ^
readConfigFile.c:51:37: error: ‘writer’ was not declared in this scope
   Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
                                     ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'readConfigFile.o' failed
make: *** [readConfigFile.o] Error 1
```

I have tried modifying the Makefile and adding "-I" option, like this:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(BUILDAGENTLIBS) -I/usr/include/rapidjson
```

But I get the same errors.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: There's not enough info in this question to give a complete answer. But for starters the error msg tells you something important: *suggested alternative: ... rapidjson::FileReadStream*. That is, looks like you need to reference the `rapidJson` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem.

Comment: Why are you compiling .c files with a C++ compiler?

Comment: My program is written in C, but I think that rapidjson uses C ++, because if I compile my program with gcc instead of g ++ I get the error:

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/rapodjson/filereadstream.h:24:0,

Comment: from example.c:1:

Comment: /usr/include/rapidjson/rapidjson.h:48:59: fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory

Comment: #include <cstdlib> // malloc(), readlloc(), free(), size_t